# TS-Morph, Is it possible to manipulate block Node to add statements?

Tags: typescript, ts-morph

I want to dynamically add statements inside an async arrow function inside a class;
I read the documentation and I didn't find anything that could help me, I was only able to get the block node where I want to insert my statements.
Is there any clean way to make it happen?

```js
  import {SyntaxKind, ArrowFunction, Block} from "ts-morph";
  //
  // .....
  // 
  let methodBody = `methodName = async(arg) => { }`;
  serviceClass.addMember(methodBody);
  let method = serviceClass.getMemberOrThrow('methodName');
  let arrowFunction =method.getDescendantsOfKind(SyntaxKind.ArrowFunction)[0];
  let block =arrowFunction.getDescendantsOfKind(SyntaxKind.Block)[0];
  ///
  /// block.addStatement('...') ???
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a method called "addStatements" which exactly suits your needs.

### Method 1: Plain Text

You could either add statements as plain text:

```
block.addStatements(
    [
        "console.log('hello');",
        "",
        "console.log('world');"
    ]);
```

### Method 2: Compiler-Nodes

If you don't care about having the code formatted accordingly, you could also use `ts-morph`s `printNode`-method:

```
import { printNode, ts } from "ts-morph";

// [...]

block.addStatements(
    [
        printNode(ts.factory.createNewExpression(ts.factory.createIdentifier("Array"))
    ]);
```

### Method 3: Nodes Prepared in Another File

Or, in order to keep your code formatted, you could also prepare the statements in another file and add it to the block afterwards.

```
let file = project.createSourceFile("temp.ts");
let varStatement = file.addVariableDeclaration(/* [...] */);

block.addStatements(
    [
        varStatement.getFullText()
    ]);
```